# C# Member Access from Nested Class to Containing Class

Tags: c#

I have ClassB, which is nested inside of ClassA. In ClassA I have a variable called _MyId... how can I access _MyId from ClassB?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

Put simply, you'll need a reference to an instance `ClassA` within `ClassB`.

C#'s nested classes work differently from Java's, if that's what you're used to. The closest analog would be Java's `static class` when applied to a nested type (meaning that C#'s nested classes are *not* associated with a particular instance of the outer class).

In other words, C#'s nested classes are not "special" when compared to outer classes, other than the fact that they have visibility into the private members of the outer class. Nonetheless, you still need a reference to the outer class in order to access them.

Answer (score 2):

In ClassB's constructor pass an instance of class A.

Answer (score 2):

If the field is `static`, you can simply refer to it as `ClassA._MyId`. If it's not you should use `classAInstance._MyId` where `classAInstance` is an instance of `ClassA`.

If you're coming from Java background, you should note that nested classes in C# are similar to **static** nested classes in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You have to refer to a particular instance of `ClassA` in order to retrieve a member.  If your instance is called `foo`, just use `foo._MyId`.

Answer (score 1):

If _MyId is static you can access it by it's name or as ClassA._MyId.

But otherwise you need an *instance* of ClassA first, and there is little difference with acces from another class (that is not nested). But members from ClassB do gain access to private members of ClassA.

Explanation: Nesting classes is a static relation between the 2 Types, there is no implicit relation between instances. You will have to pass references to objects between them just as if the classes were not nested.